# How to mute another player in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood multiplayer?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

It is very disturbing to hear all players speaking in their microphones while playing the multiplayer mode.

Is there a way to disable these sounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mute an obnoxious player:

- hit start (pause)
- select "Abstergo Agents" on the menu
- press X on the player you want to mute
- a symbol should appear by that person's name indicating they are muted / squelched

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have not seen this menu. I will check tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is available via the pause menu. I will try to get a screenshot or something.